# PyQt App activates Windows Focus Assist after NSIS installer

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, nsis

I wrote an app that reminds you to look away from the monitor every 20 minutes. It should run in the background so when a user clicks on the close button it should hide the app in the system tray and write "app minimized to tray". Note, the message should only appear when I click on the close button. On top of that there's a "minimize to tray" button inside the app itself, which does the same thing but doesn't show a pop up message.

So I created a .exe file for my app and I also wanted to create an installer. I used NSIS which was simple enough. But there's a weird behavior after using this app for a couple of times.

Here's how the app should function, and it does work like this when I run the portable version:

[image]

I used `pyinstall` to create a `--onefile` .exe for this.

Now here's the app that I installed using my NSIS installer:

[image]

As you can see, it activates windows focus assist for some reason, which prevents the app to show the notifications. Right off that, after installing the app, it does seem to work fine. The whole notifications mute happens after running it 5-6 times in a row. Re installing the app seems to solve the issue, but once again, only for a few runs. After that the issue returns.

I tried to recreate the issue with the portable version, but couldn't. It works fine. I believe it has something to do with the NSIS process.

Here's the NSIS script: https://pastebin.com/x2PjahCC

Here's the .ini file: https://pastebin.com/ptYKZGbZ

Comment: NSIS does not interact with focus assist in any way. I don't even know if there is a public API to do it.

Comment: @Anders weird because I created a new installer using Advanced Installer and it seems to work fine so far, couldn't recreate it.

Answer (score 0):

Read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/enable-desktop-toast-with-appusermodelid - Apparently, you need set the AppUserModelID - now how you successfully get this working with NSIS is beyond me.
Try: https://nsis.sourceforge.io/WinShell_plug-in or https://github.com/safing/nsis-shortcut-properties and I cant see either making an app available as a priority app.